# Linux network packet scheduler with pulse behaviour

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, scheduler

I'm looking for network packet scheduler with following behaviour:

Image we have packet transmission every milleseconds in normal mode. But we want to delay transmission to the latest 100 ms of second for all packets per second.

I mean, all packets of the first 100 ms will be delayed on 800 ms, of the second 100 ms on 700 ms and so on.

I can't find such behaviour in existing linux packet schedulers. Maybe such behaviour exists in another systems or maybe there is academic work on it.

Comment: This behaviour would be most ill-advised. The way many networks work at the "cable" layer, you can only send when either you have obtained a token (tokennet, fddi), or when nobody else is using the cable (e.g. ethernet). Which means if you concentrate 1 second worth of sends into 0.1 seconds, you'll have to drop 90% of your traffic...

Comment: Also, you greatly increase the likelihood of triggering resends, and you totally anihilate TCP bulk transfer (which relies on ACKs to move its window). If you have a timeout of 3 seconds (default value e.g. on Windows) and a somewhat long route (say, ~1 second) and both ends artificially delay the sending of packets by 0.9 seconds, then it doesn't take much to fail and trigger a resend. UDP applications with a custom reliability layer (say, a game) might already consider a packet lost after e.g. 0.5-1.0s. If you have 1.8 seconds plus 50-100ms ping as the "normal state", this will burn.

Comment: I see proper use case of this in wireless network without high load.